# How to create configurable file in Google web tool Kit

Tags: java, gwt

I am copying from my machine to some remote machine - particular location. This remote machine and location can vary so I want to create a file where changes made will reflect in my program. 
How do I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: how to create properties file in gwt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Constants](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants.html) of GWT